# Why is the Unity Launcher not revealing?

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

I set the launcher to auto-hide in ccsm and then changed reveal pressure to 1. When I move my mouse to the left side of the screen, nothing happens. There is not even a shadow along the left side of the screen when I move my mouse there.

How can I fix it? I have to go into ccsm and change the launcher to "never" hide, to bring the launcher back.

Comment: Did you upgrade Nvidia drivers? See http://askubuntu.com/a/195105

Comment: I've had this issue myself, however pressing the "special" key (AKA the Windows key) will bring up the launcher. As I tend to use keyboard short-cuts for most things this is how I mainly bring up the launcher.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Unity Dash (maybe by pressing the super (Windows) key, since your launcher is broken) and search "appearance." Open that up and go to the tab that is labelled "Behavior" and put the reveal sensitivity all the way to the right (high). That might work, or may not be the problem. I'm no expert.